Minimum information to order integers based on prime factorization without a priori knowing the order.
Suppose I give you the set $S$ that contains the integers $2$-$n$ but I have obscured it somehow so that you don’t know the true identity of S and you can’t discern the numeric notion of magnitude of an individual element. You can only distinguish elements of $S$ by the shape of their prime factorization. By this I mean $2$ and $3$ can be distinguished somehow but not in any way that reveals their magnitude or order. Similarly $12$ can be discerned as being constructed from two $2$s and a $3$ somehow but not in any way that reveals order from any other element or a notion of magnitude.
What minimum set of ordering rules could I supply you with that would guarantee your ability to arrange the elements of $S$ in ascending or descending order without revealing their number notion of magnitude?
A good start, for example, might be: For each “prime” $p$, each element constructed from $p$ must be equally spaced in the list from both the preceding and succeeding elements constructed from $p$.
This doesn’t suffice but could be one of the necessary rules.
P.S. Please feel free to edit title, body, tags as needed. Or restate it in an answer. I recently conceived this and still questioning the best way to describe it. Hopefully it made enough sense to grasp what I’m getting at.

If I understand your system, then for the entire set $S={2,3,4,5,6,7,\ldots}$ this is not possible, because the only structure we are allowed to use is the multiplicative structure. From that point of view, by keeping track solely of prime power exponents, the multiplicative monoid ${2,3,4,5,6,7,\ldots}$ is isomorphic to the direct product of infinitely many copies of the additive monoid ${0,1,2,3,4,5,6,\ldots}$ (minus its identity);  that multiplicative monoid has a huge isomorphism group consisting of the permutation group of the prime numbers.

I think that for $S = {2,3,4,5,6,7,...,n}$ this is also not possible, using permutations of the subset of primes $> n/2$; each such prime is its own unique multiple in $S$.

A natural way to make your question more formal is "suppose we equip the set ${2, 3, \dotsc, n}$ with the ternary relation that tells you whether $ab = c$. What more structure do we need to impose so that $S$ has no nontrivial automorphisms?" I think this is what Lee is talking about. If you don't know much model theory/algebra, this might be a bit bewildering. The idea is that if you have a finite set $S$ with some structure, then "we can't tell $x, y \in S$ apart" can reasonably be characterised as "there is a permutation that sends $x$ to $y$ but preserves all the structure of $S$".

I suppose the other side of that coin would be "what does the automorphism group look like?". We know that "$x$ is prime" is definable, so certainly any automorphism permutes the primes. Furthermore for any $k$, we can define "$x \le n/k$" as "$x$ has at least $k$ multiples, including itself", so any automorphism must permute primes within the intervals $(n/2, n], (n/3, n/2], (n/4, n/3], \dotsc$. It follows that primes below roughly $\sqrt n$ are all fixed. So it suffices to give the ordering of the primes in all the remaining intervals. I think there's more to say though...

@IzaakvanDongen thank you and Lee for your comments. I admit I don’t understand all you’re saying. But to make sure, do you understand that I do not want to inform the ignorant person more about the structure of $S$ at all. I simply want to give him rules for ordering the elements of $S$ based solely on information he is allowed to know about the structure (namely the prime factorization).

An example rule could be “all elements that have prime factor p must be ordered greater than p” or “no two elements that share a prime factor may be adjacent.”

We may be talking past each other a little bit here. In my comments "structure" is a fairly technical term, but it means something like "information". The point of Lee's comment is that if you are given some anonymous labels for the number $2, \dotsc, n$ as well as the information of which labels multiply to give what, this cannot be sufficient to deduce the usual ordering. You can see that because there is no way to distinguish between any primes $p, q$ with $p, q > n/2$ - they both do not have any factors or multiples. So you must give more information about the structure of $S$.
